# ¿Proyecto ruby on rails no redirecciona bien al hacer login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby

Tengo un problema a la hora de montar un proyecto de ruby on rails en apache mediante passenger, he logrado configurar un virtualhost y ver el login de la aplicación desde el navegador, pero cuando intento hacer login, intenta a redirigir a otra página y no me redirige me sale un error 302 Not Found, ¿a que se puede deber esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a S.O. en español. He borrado tu pregunta en inglés, ya que no es necesaria en esta comunidad, para que lo tengas en cuenta a futuro. En general los códigos del tipo 3xx son de redirección, para tu caso (que de hecho es "found", no "not found" que ese es un 404), debería ser normal que después de un login haga una redirección a otra página, ya sea la página de inicio del usuario, error de login, etc. ¿que te dicen los logs respecto a ese intento de inicio? ¿el tu entorno de desarrollo funciona sin problemas? ¿existe la posibilidad que no esté creado el usuario?

Comment: El problema esta yo creo en la configuración que hay entre rails+passenger+apache, cuando hago login debería redigir a otra página, es mas si lanzo el proyecto con el servidor propio de rails, las redirecciones a otras páginas las realiza sin problema.  ¿A que logs te refieres?